# Exchange online Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is there a single script that can get both Full Access and Send Us Permission of a Shared Mailbox?
Currently using two separate script that gets Full access and Send As Permission.

Hope someone can share their script if they have.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To grant FullAccess permissions to a shared mailbox you have to use the command

```
Add-MailboxPermission
```

To grant SendAs permissions you need to use the command

```
Add-RecipientPermission
```